# About programming multi-pointer apps

Tags: multi-touch, multipointerx

it could seem stupid, i am a noob in programming, but here is the question :
I search multi-pointer applications in the web (desktop, web, terminal, whatever), specifically not multi-touch but apps that support multiple mice (multi pointer) are very scarce. The well-known options in multi-touch are android, ios, and some others too, but i wanna multi-pointer ( 2 mices ).
Where can i find the answer for programming multi-pointer apps ?

...in programming language level?
...in operating system level?
...maybe is better learn to program in a multi-touch language and period XD
...other alternative?

Any hint is welcomed.

pd: One can have 2 mice in Ubuntu with the command "xinput", but one can't really take advantage of it in a useful way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to know which language you are planning to use,

but you might want to take a look at this forum post: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/reading-mouse-device-615178/

Pay special attention to

```
#define MOUSEFILE "/dev/input/event1"
```

You can specify the mouse file (everything in unix is a file) there, and if you connect more than one mouse to your system it should show up as e.g. /dev/input/mouse0, /dev/input/mouse1, /dev/input/mouse3, etc.

I suggest to start from there. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks man, i think that is going to absorb my attention for a while.I've listened that Python and Vala are pretty convenient. Now, one very good way of to hang Gnome or Unity sessions very quickly is using two mice :D. It's supposed that if desktops don't work the approach says that one could make a Desktop with a built-in multi-pointer and doesn't try to patch up "one-pointer desktops". Now, is practical this approach? or is possible other approach?

Comment: ...by the way, would be really necessary to use a multithreaded language?

Comment: I think so, since it would be able to handle multiple tasks at the same time